# Error message with the package inputenc

Tags: characters, input-encodings

I'm trying to do a presentation in spanish using `beamer` and so far my source looks like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{The Title}
\author{Carlos Márquez}
\institute{My Institution}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Introduction}
bla bla bla
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But when I compile I get the following error message: `!Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:árq not set up for use with LaTeX`. But I followed the instructions in http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization, so I don't know what is wrong. I would appreciate some help to overcome this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Most likely your file is not in utf-8 either save it in utf-8 in your editor or specifiy `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` if the file is in latin1 (iso-8859-1)

Comment: It is in latin1, but it causes trouble when loading the document in 'Write Latex', so I would like to change it to utf-8. How can I do that?

Comment: If on Windows, open it with your editor and "Save As", choosing the appropriate UTF-8 setting (assuming one exists, even Notepad has it).  If on Linux, you can do the same or use `iconv -f latin1 -t utf8 -o target.tex source.tex`.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely your file is not in `utf-8`.

Either save it in `utf-8` in your editor or specify

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

if the file is in `latin1` (`iso-8859-1`)

Most text editors will allow you to change file encoding (`save file as` menu option in most Windows systems) or a commandline utility such as `iconv` could be used

```
iconv -f latin1 -t utf8 -o target.tex source.tex
```